# how can i get sim card number of current chosen (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello Stack overflow community

I am building an app that using for dialing Unstructured Supplementary Service Data for paid services in Somalia. So what i want to do is how can i get sim card number of current chosen sim card when dialing phone.